# What is the best way to add logic to delete() on Grails domain class?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I need to make changes to other domain classes when an instance of a particular domain class is deleted. What is the best way to do this? I don't want to wait until commit or flush so I don't think the "beforeDelete" callback will help. I would like to "override" delete, do some stuff and call super.delete():

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar
    void delete() {
        if (bar) bar.foo = null
        super.delete() -- this doesn't work
    }
}
```

Currently I have named "delete" cancel but would like to call it "delete" but then I cannot call the original delete().

Comment: I would use beforeDelete and implement my logic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried overriding GORM methods myself, but this might give some insight on what's involved:

["Overloading" standard GORM CRUD methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664096/overloading-standard-gorm-crud-methods)

I would put the "delete" logic in a service and call that instead:

```
class FooService {

    def deleteInstance(foo) {
        if (foo?.bar) {
            foo.bar.foo = null
            // might have to call foo.bar.save() here
            // then foo.bar = null
        }
        foo.delete()
    }

}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to adding a cancel to the domain class but the overloading link is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To add to what @sbglasius said, here's the [link to the docs on GORM events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping)

Complete example:

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar

    def beforeDelete() {
        if(bar) {
            bar.foo = null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand beforeDelete is only called on flush? I need my model to be consistent before flush.